# how to iterate through several vectors with DIFFERENT types?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17

Here, I have a custom collection of entities (vectors of different types: `Type1`, `Type2`, `Type3` , `Type4`, for simplicity I reduced to two types) with different sizes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

template<typename DataType>
struct AbstractEntity
{
public:
    virtual std::vector<DataType>& getParticlesCPU() = 0;
    virtual void print() {};
};
// there is one of
// realization of AbstractEntity class
template<typename DataType>
class ClothEntity : public AbstractEntity<DataType>
{
public:
    ClothEntity(){
        particles.push_back(DataType(1));
        particles.push_back(DataType(2));
    }
    virtual std::vector<DataType>& getParticlesCPU() override {
        return particles;
    }
    virtual void print(){
        for (auto& a : particles)
            printf("%d\n", a.x);
    }
private:
    std::vector<DataType> particles;
};

struct Type1{
    int x;
    Type1(int x_){x = x_;}
};
struct Type2{
    int x;
    float y;
    Type2(int x_){x = x_; y = 0;}
};
class EntityCollection{
using Entity1 = AbstractEntity<Type1>;
using Entity2 = AbstractEntity<Type2>;
public:
    EntityCollection(){}
    void push_back(Entity1* entity){
        entities1.push_back(entity);
    }
    void push_back(Entity2* entity){
        entities2.push_back(entity);
    }
    std::vector<Entity1*> getEntity1(){
        return entities1;
    }
    std::vector<Entity2*> getEntity2(){
        return entities2;
    }
private:
    template< typename... Ts >
    using custom_function_t = void (*) ( Ts... );

    template<typename Entity, typename... Ts >
    double fun_per_entity( std::vector<Entity>& entities, custom_function_t<Ts...> f, Ts... args ) {
        for(auto& entity : entities){
            f(entity, args...);
        }
    }
public:
    template<typename... Ts >
    void run_function(custom_function_t<Ts...> f, Ts... args){
        fun_per_entity(entities1, f, args...);
        fun_per_entity(entities2, f, args...);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Entity1*> entities1;
    std::vector<Entity2*> entities2;
};

    
int main()
{
    EntityCollection ec;
    ClothEntity<Type1> e1;
    ClothEntity<Type2> e2;
    ec.push_back(&e1);
    ec.push_back(&e2);
    // ec.run_function(print); // does not work
    for (auto& ev: ec.getEntity1())
        ev->print();
    for (auto& ev: ec.getEntity2())
        ev->print();

    return 0;
}
```

**My goal is safely iterate over all vectors (entities1, entities2, ...) to run a given external function `f_external(Entity e, Args...)`**:

```
for (auto& e : entities1)
    f_external(e, args...) 

for (auto& e : entities2)
    f_external(e, args...)
```

**or internal function `f_internal(Args...)`:**

```
for (auto& e : entities1)
    e->f_internal(args...) 
    
for (auto& e : entities2)
    e->f_internal(args...)
```

Right now, I am writing a lot of code each time:

```
EntityCollection ec;
for (auto& e : ec.getEntity1())
    e->f_internal(args...)
for (auto& e : ec.getEntity2())
    e->f_internal(args...)
```

How to automate it in order to minimize the mistakes and changes with adding new Types? I would be grateful if you use `C++17`.

Comment: I dont understand the question. The code you would like to write is two loops. The code you have to write is also two loops. The only difference is `entities1` vs `ec.getEntity1()`

Comment: Have you considered writing a function which performs the two loops using a given functor?

Comment: In C++20 there is std::ranges::views::join

Comment: How I mentioned, the number of types can be arbitrary and I want to avoid writing `getEntity1()`, `getEntity2`, etc. The question is how to avoid direct declaration of thesse function and iterate through all vectors, entity1, entity2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `run_function` member function take a functor instead of a function pointer:

```cpp
    template<typename Entity, typename F, typename... Ts>
    static void fun_per_entity(std::vector<Entity*>& entities, F&& f, Ts&&... args) {
        for (auto& entity : entities) {
            f(entity, args...);
        }
    }
public:
    template<typename F, typename... Ts>
    void run_function(F&& f, Ts&&... args) {
        fun_per_entity(entities1, f, args...);
        fun_per_entity(entities2, f, args...);
        fun_per_entity(entities3, f, args...);
        // ...
    }
```

And you can use it with a lambda:

```cpp
ec.run_function([&](auto* e) { f_external(e, args...); });
ec.run_function([&](auto* e) { e->f_internal(args...); });
```

---

Also consider making `template<typename DataType> class AbstractEntity` derive from some non-template base so you only need one vector

Comment: Thank you for an elegant solution! Could you give a hint how to automate calling of `fun_per_entity(entities1, f, args...);`  for a given list of `Entity1, Entity2, etc.`? maybe using macros?

Comment: @EugeneW. It's a pretty short bit of code, and using a macro would probably make it longer. Other solutions would have a lot more lines of code and be more confusing. Here's one way you can rewrite your `EntityCollection` class to become a template that has a tuple of vectors, and you only have to have the list of types in one place: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vd8Aeeoi83owQZhV (but you'll find out pretty fast that tuples are more annoying to work with than multiple members)

Comment: Thank you for a hint, but a link does not work

Comment: @EugeneW. This one should: https://godbolt.org/z/s57MMzMPz